# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorExceptionORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am using this query

```
sql=String.format("INSERT INTO  PM_AM_ASSET_AUDIT(TAG_ID,MODEL_ID,CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,NOTES,STATUS_ID,PARK_ID,TOWER_ID,FLOOR_ID,UNIT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,CHECK_OUT_DATE,DUE_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,REVISION,PARK_NAME,TOWER_NAME,FLOOR_NAME,UNIT_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME)
                   SELECT TAG_ID,MODEL_ID,CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,NOTES,STATUS_ID,PARK_ID,TOWER_ID,FLOOR_ID,UNIT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,CHECK_OUT_DATE,DUE_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,REVISION,PARK_NAME,TOWER_NAME,FLOOR_NAME,UNIT_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME 
                   FROM  PM_AM_ASSET_MASTER where id ="+id);
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql,new String[] {"ID"});
```

but, I got this exception

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

When I remove generated keys concept the query executes.

Answer (score 1):

Newer use concatenation in your statements to prevent sql injection.

Try this case:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PM_AM_ASSET_AUDIT " +
    "      (TAG_ID,MODEL_ID,CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,NOTES,STATUS_ID,PARK_ID,TOWER_ID,FLOOR_ID,UNIT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,CHECK_OUT_DATE,DUE_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,REVISION,PARK_NAME,TOWER_NAME,FLOOR_NAME,UNIT_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME) " +
    "SELECT TAG_ID,MODEL_ID,CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,NOTES,STATUS_ID,PARK_ID,TOWER_ID,FLOOR_ID,UNIT_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,CHECK_OUT_DATE,DUE_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,REVISION,PARK_NAME,TOWER_NAME,FLOOR_NAME,UNIT_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME " +
    "FROM PM_AM_ASSET_MASTER where id = ?";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
p.setString(1, id);
```